# Derivation of a fraction $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{x+8}{9x^2\cdot e^x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been given the fraction of

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{x+8}{9x^2\cdot e^x}$$

I can derive the $f(x)$ which is equal to $1$, however when I try to derive $g(x)=9x^2\cdot e^x$ I seem to be missing some steps.

The correct answer is $18xe^x+9x^2\cdot e^x$   How exactly do I get this answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule

Comment: Since $(f(x)g(x))'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$, we have
$9x^2*e^x=(9x^2)'*e^x+9x^2*(e^x)'=18x*e^x+9x^2*e^x=(18x+9x^2)e^x$

Comment: Just a note, the verb form of "derivative" is "differentiate" not "derive". So you would say "I can differentiate the function" not "I can derive the function".

Answer (score 2):

> however when I try to derive $g(x)=9x^2\cdot e^x$ I seem to be missing some steps.
>
> The correct answer is $18xe^x+9x^2\cdot e^x$.   How exactly do I get this answer?

One may recall that
$$
(uv)'=u'v+uv'
$$ giving
$$
(9x^2\cdot e^x)'=(9\cdot 2x)\cdot e^x+9x^2\cdot (e^x)=18xe^x+9x^2e^x
$$ using that $(e^x)'=e^x$.

Answer (score 2):

In general we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \times g(x) - \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x} \times f(x)}{g^2(x)}$. So in the case of your question, set $f(x)= x+ 8$ and $g(x) = 9 x^2 \times e^x $. And we have:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x+ 8) = 1$ and

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (9 x^2 \times e^x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(9 x^2 ) \times  e^x + (9 x^2) \times \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (e^x) = 18 x \times e^x  + 9 x^2 \times e^x = (18 x + 9 x^2) \times e^x  $. So we have:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{x+ 8}{9 x^2 \times e^x}= \frac{1 \times (9 x^2 \times e^x) - ((18 x + 9 x^2) \times e^x) \times (x+ 8)}{(9 x^2 \times e^x)^2} = \frac{-x^2 -9x+16}{9 x^3}$.

And we are done.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{x+8}{9x^2\cdot e^x}\right)=\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{x+8}{x^2\cdot e^x}\right)=$$

---

Use the product rule:

---

$$\frac{1}{9}\cdot\left(\frac{(8+x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^{-x}\right)}{x^2}+e^{-x}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{8+x}{x^2}\right)\right)=$$

---

Use the product rule again:

---

$$\frac{1}{9}\cdot\left(\frac{(8+x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^{-x}\right)}{x^2}+e^{-x}\cdot\left((8+x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(8+x)}{x^2}\right)\right)=$$

---

Differentiate the sum term by term:

---

$$\frac{1}{9}\cdot\left(\frac{(8+x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^{-x}\right)}{x^2}+e^{-x}\cdot\left((8+x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(x)+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(8)}{x^2}\right)\right)$$